# getResourceAsStream returns NullpointException (spring4)

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, fileinputstream

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/all", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<List<ItemVO>> listAll() {
    ResponseEntity<List<ItemVO>> entity = null;
    try {


        List<ItemVO> list=service.listAll();
        for(ItemVO i : list){
            InputStream in = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(i.getFilepath_img()); 

            i.setByte_img(IOUtils.toByteArray(in));

        }
          final HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
            headers.setContentType(MediaType.IMAGE_PNG);
        entity = new ResponseEntity<List<ItemVO>>(list, HttpStatus.OK);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        e.printStackTrace();
        entity = new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }

    return entity;
}
```

VO

```
 public class ItemVO{
    private int item_id;
    private String filepath_img;
    private byte[] byte_img;
}
```

The image is located in  src/main/webapp/resources/img folder,

stored file path is like "/img/xxx.png"

i have no idea what to do
Stack trace :

java.lang.NullPointerException

```
at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copyLarge(IOUtils.java:2146)

at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copy(IOUtils.java:2102)

at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copyLarge(IOUtils.java:2123)

at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copy(IOUtils.java:2078)

at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.toByteArray(IOUtils.java:721)
```

Comment: did you check `i.getFilepath_img()` return path ?

Comment: yes, i did  it works well

Comment: try with this path for checking purpose `main/webapp/resources/img/xxx.png`

Comment: it doesnt work..

Comment: ClassLoader can access resources from classpath. On compile the image is not added to classpath but copied to resources. When you start your web application sources are not available and requested resource is not under your classpath. Try to use webapp/resources/img but actually it depends on your deploymnet -war or springboot jar.

Comment: is image file is available on that location ? check extension too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`webapp/resources/..` is not in the classpath. You could solve this by using a [`ServletContext`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html)

Inject it:

```
@Autowired
private ServletContext servletContext;
```

Then get the `InputStream`:

```
InputStream in = servletContext.getResourceAsStream(i.getFilepath_img());
```

This code assumes that:

- `getFilepath_img()` returns an absolute path relatives to your webapp context, eg. `/resources/img/xxx.png`. If not, you should prepend the path eg. `"/resources/" + i.getFilepath_img()` with or without the resources tailing `/`

Answer (score 0):

[Spring’s Resource](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/resources.html) interface is meant to be a more capable interface for abstracting access to low-level resources.

You should inject/autowire a [ResourceLoader](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/resources.html#resources-resourceloader) and use it to obtain the resource. All application contexts implement the ResourceLoader interface, and therefore all application contexts may be used to obtain Resource instances.

For example:

```
@Autowired
private ResourceLoader context;
```

And then:

```
Resource image = context.getResource(i.getFilepath_img());
InputStream is = image.getInputStream();
...
```

This will enable you to specify the file path as URL, file or classpath resource, or let if depend on the underlying ApplicationContext. See [Table 8.1 Resource Strings](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/resources.html#resources-resource-strings) for more information.